# EasyPeasy store hook causes rerender upon any state change

Tags: redux, state, easy-peasy

We currently have a redux state with nested models with the following structure.

```
{
  groups: {
    ids: [],
    status: {},
    error: {}
  },
  members: {
    ids: [],
    status: {},
    error: {}
}
```

For convenience, each model has an exported hook, typed as;

```
export const useGroupState = () => useTypedState((state) => state.groups);
```

And used like so;

```
const { ids } = useGroupState()
```

We use this syntax throughout our app. However we recently noticed that upon *any* state change to the GroupState, even if it does not modify ids, causes a rerender. If Groups.status updates, anything destructing with the above syntax will rerender.

We solved this by using

```
const ids = useTypedState(({groups}) => groups.ids)
```

However, the old syntax is convenient and is fairly widespread. Is there a way we could retain the old syntax but fix the re-render behavior?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the exact implementation of the `useTypedState` hook here, but assuming it uses the [React-Redux `useSelector` hook inside](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates): yes, this is entirely expected behavior.  **`useSelector` re-renders if the returned reference has changed since last time**.  If you return an object, and that object gets immutably updated, then it's a new reference and will force a re-render. Destructuring only some of the fields happens *after* the render is in progress.

[Your component should always select the smallest amount of actual state that it needs](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-5-ui-react#using-multiple-selectors-in-a-component).